# Unable to add transaction_id column in model for using on watson openscale

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-openscale, unique-transaction-identifier

To view transactions on Watson OpenScale, a transaction id field is required. I cannot add this field while training the model and cannot add this field after the model has been trained.

How can I add this column to view transactions on Watson OpenScale for a deployed model

Comment: By 'To view transactions on Watson OpenScale', do you mean using the explainability feature on Watson OpenScale?

Answer (score 0):

Once  the model is trained and  whenever data is sent to the WML model for scoring, transaction ID gets stored in the payload logging table.

Note:For Non WML models, you need to send the scoring id when you do the scoring.

Comment: This id is not getting generated for my current wml model